# Issues reshaping dataframe in python: pivot and groupby not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to reshape the following dataframe:

```
            year    production     diversity
code_city           
10701       2007    1096895.118        97
10701       2008    1485981.356       101
10701       2009    1592737.910       110
10702       2007    1196895.116        95
10702       2008    1285981.355       102
10702       2009    1392737.913       111
10703       2007    1496895.112        92
10703       2008    1585981.351       105
10703       2009    1692737.916       116
```

and the required output is:

```
                         production    diversity    

10701       2007-12-31  1096895.118        97
            2008-12-31  1485981.356       101
            2009-12-31  1592737.910       110
10702       2007-12-31  1196895.116        95
            2008-12-31  1285981.355       102
            2009-12-31  1392737.913       111
10703       2007-12-31  1496895.112        92
            2008-12-31  1585981.351       105
            2009-12-31  1692737.916       116
```

I've been using this:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df_firms1, index=['code_city', 'year'], columns=['production', 'diversity'])
```

but I'm getting a lot of errors. Is it a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df_firms1.reset_index(), 
                       index=['code_city', 'year'], 
                       columns=['production', 'diversity'])
```

But with sample data get:

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

So need convert `year` column to datetimes and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with parameter `append=True` for `MultiIndex` with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove index names:

```
df_firms1['year'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df_firms1['year'], freq='A').to_timestamp(how='e')

#alternative solution
#df_firms1['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_firms1['year'], format='%Y') + pd.offsets.YearEnd()

df_firms1 = df_firms1.set_index('year', append=True).rename_axis([None, None])
print (df_firms1)

                   production  diversity
10701 2007-12-31  1096895.118         97
      2008-12-31  1485981.356        101
      2009-12-31  1592737.910        110
10702 2007-12-31  1196895.116         95
      2008-12-31  1285981.355        102
      2009-12-31  1392737.913        111
10703 2007-12-31  1496895.112         92
      2008-12-31  1585981.351        105
      2009-12-31  1692737.916        116
```

Comment: it works!... but how can I erase the indexes names: 'code_city' and 'year' ? @jazrael.

Comment: @PAstudilloE - Added function [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) ;)